# form data api request from apex with two or more key-value pairs

Tags: apex, rest-api, api

Not getting the expected response. Is the body of the request correct?

```
------------1612520644919
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="auth_key"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: text/plain
xyz
------------1612520644919
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="opportunity_id"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: text/plain
123456
------------1612520644919
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: text/plain
exp
------------1612520644919
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mobile_number"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: text/plain
1234567890
------------1612520644919
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email_id"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: text/plain
test@xyz.com
------------1612520644919--
```

Comment: Can you include more specific details? What response are you expecting? What response are you getting? Can you tell us what API you are calling? Most likely, this is a misunderstanding with the API you are using and not necessarily a question related to Apex code.

Comment: it was an issue with request body. Solved now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your multipart form is incorrect. You need a newline after the headers for each form element and another new line after the body.

```
------------1612520644919
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="auth_key"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: text/plain

xyz

------------1612520644919
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="opportunity_id"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: text/plain

123456

------------1612520644919
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: text/plain

exp

------------1612520644919
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mobile_number"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: text/plain

1234567890

------------1612520644919
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email_id"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: text/plain

test@xyz.com

------------1612520644919--
```